# Post and Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer

I set up a contact form and posted something. And then I got an error message.

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Could you help me?

☆heroku logs

```
013-12-17T13:14:55.445509+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 118.237.94.47 at 2013-12-17 13:14:55 +0000
2013-12-17T13:14:55.450507+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2013-12-17T13:14:55.450838+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2e9zz3cX0tZwYTZhaPbRRYQuZrGi31fZk4OjjF7sdeo=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"荒牧さん", "email"=>"sun@gmail.com", "content"=>"どうなんすか！"}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
2013-12-17T13:14:55.549141+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contact_mailer/sent.text.erb (0.6ms)
2013-12-17T13:14:55.573616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/contacts host=www.tsundoku-buster.jp fwd="118.237.94.47" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=136ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-12-17T13:14:55.570589+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-17T13:14:55.570589+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to suncountry99@gmail.com (16ms)
2013-12-17T13:14:55.570797+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 120ms
2013-12-17T13:14:55.572327+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-17T13:14:55.572327+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2013-12-17T13:14:55.572327+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

☆contacts_controller

```
 #encoding: utf-8 
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
      def create
       @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
       if @contact.save
        ContactMailer.sent(@contact).deliver
        redirect_to static_pages_contact_path, :notice => 'お問い合わせありがとうございました。'
      else
        render static_pages_contact_path, :alert => 'お問い合わせに不備があります。'
      end
     end
end
```

Comment: what's on `app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:6:in 'create'`? :)

Comment: Me neither. I guess you should paste some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the contact controller is trying to send an email. In fact, from the logs I see the `ContactMailer.sent` method was called.

Heroku does not allow you to send emails using the internal SMTP. You need to use one of the Heroku add-on.

See the article [Sending Email from Your App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp). The majority of Heroku email add-ons, such as SendGrid, are very straightforward to integrate in your Rails app.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Simone Carletti, I followed your instruction but still the error remains.

Comment: Which add-on you used? How do you configured it? Provide details. I hope you didn't just installed the add-on. Unless you configure Rails to use it, you will keep getting the same error.

Comment: I used SendGrid. I could not get an email yet but removed the error by commenting in. @config/environments/production.rb

# Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
⇒
# Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

Comment: You did not follow my instructions, that's why you are getting the same error. You can't send emails in such way in Heroku, **you need to install an email add-on and switch to it**. Please carefully read my answer and the documentation I linked.

Comment: No, I installed SendGrid, following your instruction.

Comment: Update the question and include your ActionMailer::Base sendgrid configuration, along with the relevant settings in the environments.

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded new question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648985/socketerror-getaddrinfo-name-or-service-not-known-and-netsmtpfatalerror-5

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same error, and it was because elasticsearch service not running. simply did:
`sudo service elasticsearch start`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was cause by fail2ban. Just edit your /etc/fail2ban/jail.local file and disable [ssh] and [ssh-ddos] by setting enabled = false in the jail.local file.

`$ sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`