# Sendgrid/can't get emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

Now I am trying to set up a contact form and removed all the errors.But I can't get email.Could you give me some advice?

☆heroku logs

```
 2013-12-18T06:20:34.807594+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 118.237.94.47 at 2013-12-18 06:20:34 +0000
2013-12-18T06:20:34.813037+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2013-12-18T06:20:34.813037+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2e9zz3cX0tZwYTZhaPbRRYQufff31fZk4OjjF7sdeo=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"じゃじゃじゃ", "email"=>"jaja@gmail.com", "content"=>"じゃじゃじゃ"}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
2013-12-18T06:20:34.843217+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contact_mailer/sent.text.erb (0.5ms)
2013-12-18T06:20:35.265031+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/contacts host=www.tsundoku-buster.jp fwd="118.237.94.47" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=464ms status=302 bytes=116
2013-12-18T06:20:35.259745+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-18T06:20:35.259745+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to myemail@gmail.com (412ms)
2013-12-18T06:20:35.260551+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.tsundoku-buster.jp/static_pages/contact
2013-12-18T06:20:35.260715+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 448ms (ActiveRecord: 11.4ms)
```

What I have done so far is as follows.

①app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.contact_mailer.sent.subject
  #
  def sent(contact)
    @contact = contact

    mail(:to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => 'TsundokuBuster発お問い合わせ')
  end
end
```

②app/views/contact_mailer/sent.text.erb

```
以下の内容でお問い合わせ頂きました。
お名前
<%= @contact.name %>

メールアドレス
<%= @contact.email %>

お問い合わせ内容
<%= @contact.content %>
```

③contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :content
  validates :name, :email, :content , :presence => true
end
```

cf.http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

④contacts_controller.rb

```
 #encoding: utf-8 
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
      def create
       @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
       if @contact.save
        ContactMailer.sent(@contact).deliver
        redirect_to static_pages_contact_path, :notice => 'お問い合わせありがとうございました。'
      else
        render static_pages_contact_path, :alert => 'お問い合わせに不備があります。'
      end
     end
end
```

⑤Adding Sendgrid add-on at heroku dashboard

⑥Search for my SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD

cf.https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

⑦Editing config/environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['myappusername@heroku.com'],
  :password       => ENV['mypassword'],
  :domain         => 'www.mydomain.jp',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

⑧git add. git commit git push heroku master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all beginners.

Just do "heroku config" on your command.
Then you will get something like this.

```
SENDGRID_PASSWORD:          xxxxxxxxx
SENDGRID_USERNAME:          xxxxxxx@heroku.com
```

This is hash. So if you want to hide your password as well as username, you should write the code like

```
:password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'] 
:user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
```

If you don't mind to show your password, you can write this as follows;

```
:password => xxxxxxxxx
:user_name => xxxxxxx@heroku.com
```

Comment: Best practice is to do it the first way using environment variables. Not only does it prevent your password from being under version control, but it also allows you to change your password without redeploying. It further allows you to have different credentials between staging and production.